# Antlr grammar not matching expected lexer rule

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to match a duration string, like `for 30 minutes` or `for 2 hours` using the following rules:

```
durationPhrase: FOR_STR (MINUTE_DURATION | HOUR_DURATION);

MINUTE_DURATION: NONZERO_NUMBER MINUTE_STR;

HOUR_DURATION: NONZERO_NUMBER HOUR_STR;

MINUTE_STR: 'minute'('s')?;

HOUR_STR: 'hour'('s')?;

FOR_STR: 'for';

NONZERO_NUMBER: [0-9]+;

WS: (' '|[\n\t\r]) -> skip;
```

With the following input:

```
for 30 minutes
```

Attempting to debug/match the `durationPhrase` rule, I'm presented with the error:

```
line 1:4 mismatched input '30' expecting {MINUTE_DURATION, HOUR_DURATION}
```

But I can't seem to figure out what lexer rule the '30' is matching? I was under the impression the "longest" lexer rule would win, which **would be** the `MINUTE_DURATION` rule.

Is it instead matching `NONZERO_NUMBER` first? And if so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's matching `NONZERO_NUMBER` because neither of the other patterns apply. If you had entered `30minutes`, it would have matched `MINUTE_DURATION`, but as a token pattern, `MINUTE_DURATION` won't match the space character.

You ignore whitespace by applying `-> skip` to the token `WS`. That can only happen after `WS` is recognised as a token; i.e. after tokenisation. During tokenisation, whitespace characters are just characters.

If you make `MINUTE_DURATION` and `HOUR_DURATION` syntax rules rather than lexical rules, it should work as expected.